# algorithmic complexity of following code snippet

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

we're all know that for a code snippet like

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ //do something}
```

Has a complexity of O(n) and we can find it:

**sum symbol** from n=0 to n-1 c1 = c1* ((n-1)*n)/2

What if the code will be :

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i+=2){ //do something}
```

I dont only interested in with  big o notation but also,exact growth rate function.

Is there anyone to help me ? thanks in advance

Comment: The complexity shall be same as earlier loop. O(n) not O(n^2)

Comment: As far as I can see, your first statement is O(n), unless something else O(n) happens in the loop...

Comment: Complexity of both the loops will be same accordint to me and it would be O(n) and not O(n^2)

Comment: I've corrected it, sorry for mistake

Answer (score 3):

The `//do something` shall be executed n/2 times .

```
Hence complexity = O(n/2) = O(n) (same as the previous loop)
```

Practically obviously the second loop will take less time as it only executes half the number of statements. However as n grows, the growth in time complexity shall be **linear** for both the loops.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) { /* do something */ }
```

It has unknown complexity where we don't know about `/* do something */`. If the loop's body  hasn't inner loops based on `n`. It has complexity *O(n)*.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i+=2) { /* do something */ }
```

As same as above, this has complexity *O(n)* too. Note that *O(n/2) = O(n)*.

Answer (score 1):

When you take Big O notation , we assume n is a positive set .

N can grow in 2 ways 
1-Linearly 
2-Exponentially

N grows exponentially if we multiply n by an integer >1. Consider the code snippet

```
for(i=1;i<n;i=i*2){
```

}

here n increase by a large value, i.e, 2,4,8,16,32....

N grows linearly if we increment n by an integer>0( The code that you gave grows linearly )

For linear growth, Time complexity is O(n)

For exponential growth, Time complexity is O(logn)

Lets consider another example

```
for(i=0;i<n*10;i++){//has Complexity O(n)
```

}

```
for(i=0;i<n*n;i++){//has Complexity O(n*n)
```

}

This is because 10 is a constant and n is not a constant